# Why does the Gram-Schmidt procedure divide by 0 on a linearly dependent lists of vectors?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

Let $v_1, \dots, v_m$ be a linearly dependent list of vectors.
If $v_1 \ne 0$, then there is some $v_j$ in the span of $v_1, \dots, v_{j-1}$
If we let j be the smallest integer with this property, and apply the gram-schmidt procedure to produce an orthonormal list $(e_1, \dots, e_{j-1})$ then $v_j$ is in the span of $(e_1, \dots, e_{j-1})$ and
$$v_j = \langle v_j, e_1\rangle e_1+ \dots + \langle v_j, e_{j-1}\rangle e_{j-1}$$
Why does this guarantee that length of $v_j$=0? I'm missing something about linear dependence that should probably be obvious sorry :\

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Gram-Schmidt process goes as follows: given $v_1,\ldots,v_n$, you define
$$\begin{align*}
u_1 &= v_1\\
e_1 &= \frac{1}{||u_1||}u_1;\\
u_2 &= v_2 - \langle v_2,e_1\rangle e_1;\\
e_2 &= \frac{1}{||u_2||}u_2;\\
&\vdots\\
u_{k+1} &= v_{k+1} - \left(\langle v_{k+1},e_1\rangle e_1 + \langle v_{k+1},e_2\rangle e_2 + \cdots + \langle v_{k+1},e_k\rangle e_k\right)\\
e_{k+1}&= \frac{1}{||u_{k+1}||}u_{k+1}\\
&\vdots
\end{align*}$$

So when you construct $u_{j}$, you get $\mathbf{0}$, and when you try to construct $e_{j}$ you attempt to divide by $0$. It's not $v_j$ which has length $0$, it's $u_j$.

Comment: @Arturo - can you explain why does it follow that $u_j$ is 0? I understand that $v_j$ is in the span of its previous vectors, which means *there is* a linear combination of them which equals to $v_j$, but why is it a must that its this particular combination?

Comment: For anyone wondering - this follows from the fact that for any vector $v$ and any basis $w_1, w_2, \cdots , w_k$, one can always express $v = \sum_{i=0}^k \langle v, w_k \rangle w_k$.

Comment: The formula above holds when the basis $w_1,\ldots,w_k$ is orthonormal. When the basis is orthogonal, you need to divide each summand by $\langle w_k,w_k\rangle$. Basically, the expression we are subtracting in the G-S process is the orthogonal projection of $v_{k+1}$ onto $\mathrm{span}(u_1,\ldots,u_k)$; if $v_{k+1}$ is already in the span, we are subtracting $v_{k+1}$ itself, and hence we get $0$.

Answer (score 2):

It does not guarantee that.  What it guarantees is that $v_j - \langle v_j, e_1\rangle e_1- \dots - \langle v_j, e_{j-1}\rangle e_{j-1} = 0$, which means that you cannot define $e_j$ by dividing this vector by its norm.  Instead, you throw it away and move on to $v_{j+1}$.

E.g., consider the case $v_1\neq 0$ and $v_2=v_1$.

Comment: @Jonas - can you explain why does it follow that $v_j$ minus the projections of the others is 0? linear dependence means that there is a linear combination of the previous vectors which equals to $v_j$, but why is it a must that its this particular combination?

Comment: @ihadanny: It is 0 because it is a vector in the span of the $e_i$s whose inner product with each $e_i$ is 0.

Comment: @Jonas - let me rephrase that to see if I understood correctly. $u_j$ is in the span of the $e_i$s. This means that we can write $u_j$ as a linear combination of those $e_i$s. A linear combination of *orthogonal vectors* is a sum of the inner product with each of them. But since we made sure that the inner product of $u_j$ with each of the $e_i$ would be 0, the entire sum would be 0.