# Gram-Schmidt process - Division by zero (ERROR)

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products, integer-lattices, vector-lattices

I'm working with full-rank lattice basis, and I need to compute the Gram-Schmidt **norms** and **coefficients** to measure its quality. But during the process I have a division by 0.

The division by zero is normal when the vectors are not linear dependent, which is not the case. Others said that I should throw it away and move to the next vector. But I need all the coefficients and norms to solve my next problem.

What should I do to compute all the coefficients and norms?

```
 B[]  = (Full-rank Basis)
 c[]  = (Gram-Schmidt Norms)
 mu[] = (Gram-Schmidt Coefficients)

 for(k=0; k < NUM_VECTORS; k=k+1) {

    if(k==1) c[0] = InnerProduct(B[0], B[0]);
    c[k] = InnerProduct(B[k], B[k]);

    for (j=0; j<k; j=j+1) {
        s = InnerProduct(B[k], B[j]);

        for(i=0; i<j; i++)
            s -= mu[j][i] * mu[k][i] * c[i];

        s = s / c[j]; //<--- PROBLEM IS HERE (DIVISION BY ZERO) c[j] is 0!!

        mu[k][j] = s;
        c[k] -= s * s * c[j];
    }
}
```

You can also see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/29672/why-does-the-gram-schmidt-procedure-divide-by-0-on-a-linearly-dependent-lists-of).

Comment: Is there any particular reason you can't use a standard QR routine from e.g. LAPACK?

Comment: I need to do very efficient implementation, and this algorithm allows me better execution times. I'm trying to avoid the main routine. Is that the only solution?

Comment: Provided that you compile your BLAS and ATLAS on the machine that is running them, you will probably not get more efficient than LAPACK's implementation while also avoiding pitfalls like this one. It's not the only solution, but your code basically needs if/else logic to catch this issue before it happens.

Comment: Ok, but to use LAPACK for example I need to convert the basis. It will lost an amount of time in bases conversions.

Comment: You mean you need only the entries of R, not the entries of Q? Computing the entries of Q along the way is, to my understanding, more numerically stable than trying to directly compute the entries of R without orthogonalizing along the way. Also, it wouldn't surprise me if you were falling into the trap of premature optimization. How large is your problem?

Comment: @Ian, Yes I need to catch the issue. But I don't know what I must do, when I catch it. Just ignore the vector? I'm implementing an SVP solver that do several calls to this routine.

Comment: Once c[j] is zero, that vector has already been completely orthogonalized, there is no more component to be projected. I think that should answer your question if you think about the math for a moment. Also, that does not tell me very much. How large are the matrices, and to within an order of magnitude, how many times do you need to call the routine on such matrices? If the answers are "less than $100 \times 100$" and "less than 1000 times", then you are optimizing quite prematurely.